# React Native for loop TouchableOpacity scope JSX

Tags: reactjs

```
  const result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 2 && i < ar.length; i++) {
    result.push(  
      <>
      <Countdown dateObj = {ar[i].time} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
        console.log("SENDING DATA", ar[i]);
        navigation.navigate("ChatInterface", {data: ar[i]});
      }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
    );
  }
...
return <>{result}</>;
```

I put everything inside a for loop so I can return them all at once later using `return <>{result}</>. However,

ar[i] is coming out as undefined. Even though the line above involving `Countdown` works fine. I'm thinking it has something to do with the scope of the anonymous function inside TouchableOpacity. How can I get this to work?

Comment: do you mind adding more of your code.  Perhaps the entire scope of your parent component to better see what is going on with the render cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong.

The issue is that the TouchableOpacity code doesn't execute at the same time 'i' is incremented. It is executed way later than the end of the for loop, even though the "i" variable stays the same.

So when it gets to the TouchableOpacity code, the for loop is already broken, and 'i' is out of range. So when i try to access it, the item at that index i is undefined.

Serves me right for trying to be clever with the for loop, I guess.

I fixed it by making another reference to my data. Instead of referring directly to `ar[i]`, I first made a copy `const dat = ar[i]` and referred to `dat` inside my TouchableOpacity.